# intelliJ: option+return to import not working

Tags: intellij-idea

If place my selection on an unresolved variable (*roles* in below image) and press option+return I'm supposed to get suggestions on imports that I can add to resolve the variable.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I don't get the import suggestions anymore. I think this broke two updates ago, for me.

Adding imports on the fly still works. Import suggestions when I add imports by typing still works.

Any idea on what is wrong with my settings? I'm developing in Javascript using IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: not enough info to see what's wrong. Is the issue specific to this file/variable? Do you have **Missing import statement** inspection enabled in **Preferences | Editor | Inspections JavaScript | General**? Please also check the **JavaScript | General | Unresolved JavaScript function** and **JavaScript | General | Unresolved JavaScript variable** inspections

Comment: Enabling "Missing import statement" fixed it. Thanks! Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that  **Missing import statement** inspection is enabled in **Preferences | Editor | Inspections JavaScript | General**.

Please also check the **JavaScript | General | Unresolved JavaScript function** and **JavaScript | General | Unresolved JavaScript variable** inspections